# Get installed apps at Google Play Store - PHP

Tags: php, google-play, google-play-services

Is it possible to get the apps that a user has installed at Google Play Store? I would like to get a list of his ratings so I need the apps which he has installed.

Is there a way to get these information? Maybe a Google Play Store API? I want to access the data via PHP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Google Play have an API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661434/does-google-play-have-an-api)

Answer (score 1):

I very much doubt you will be able to get this information, Google will not just give out the information of what users have installed what apps.

You can use something like http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/ to search apps/comments/possibly ratings but getting specific user specific data is not supported.

Comment: Is it possible to login to a google account with curl and then read out the source code?

Comment: If it uses cookie based sessions then sure, take a look at the COOKIEJAR and COOKIEFILE CURL options.